# gunicorn using the same worker process for all requests

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

I am running gunicorn with the gevent worker type and 3 workers on a 2 core system.
I send about 15 concurrent requests to the server.
The avg time for each request when run individually is 20 seconds, but it goes up to 30 when run concurrently.

Looking at the logs for gunicorn, I can see that each request is being handled by the same worker (tracked using process id in logs).
Could this be a possible reason why the avg time is so much higher? Since the same process is handling all requests, presumably there's constant context switches. 
How do I ensure that all the worker processes are used?
I tried increasing the number of workers, but that wasn't much help.

Here's the part of the config file that starts gunicorn as a service:

```
/usr/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/pid --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/socket myapp.wsgi:application -k gevent -w 3 --worker-connections 1000 --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --access-logformat "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" %(p)s"
```

Comment: Could you provide the command you're using to start Gunicorn? Or the configuration file, if you're using one? It's possible there could be a config issue.

Comment: How exactly did you log the process id?

Comment: @KlausD: the %(p)s logs the process id of the worker (as described here: docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format

Comment: Show us the code for that!

Comment: In the edit I provided above, the --access-log-format "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" %(p)s" logs each request coming in to gunicorn, and the %(p)s logs the process ID for the request